# register an android broadcast receiver statically using python

Tags: android, python, broadcastreceiver, kivy, android-broadcast

I have a python-kivy android app and I need to use a receiver, it must be a static receiver because I need use it even app is not running. I know I have to include it in the manifest.
My questions are: 
Is possible to do it in python or must I do it in java?

Perhaps, i have to do the receiver in java and the rest of the app with python?

Thanks

Comment: You can look at [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) for some examples of this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, but plyer have nothing about static receivers or receivers, just for notifications. I already used it.